# XSL substring on Template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a template that I do a conditional upon, however I would like to get a tokenized version of each piece of xml

```
<xsl:when test="/o:page/o:config/descendant::o:menu.disabled/text() = @id and substring-before(o:page/o:config/descendant::o:menu.disabled/text(),',') = 'stuff'" />
```

The xml data contains things like "stuff,1023" so I would only like to run the conditional on the "stuff" component of the string. Any help would be great cheers.

I'm using xsl version 1.0

(I am quite fully aware of why the above won't work, but I thought I would add the substring-before in front of it just as way to show what I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 1):

To test if a text node containing delimited values includes a specific item, you can do:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(concat(',', your-node, ','), ',stuff,')">
```